# Unable to delete nested content controls in Word with Office JS

Tags: typescript, ms-word, office-js

I'm writing a Word add-in using Office JS. I have created a Word document that has a structure like the following:

```
<OuterContentControl tag="Outer" cannotDelete>
    <InnerContentControl tag="Inner" cannotDelete />
</OuterContentControl>
```

I'm trying to delete the inner content control with code similar to this:

```
async function delete() {

    await Word.run(async (context) => {
        const contentControls = context.document.contentControls.getByTag('Inner').load();
        await context.sync();

        contentControls.items.forEach(contentControl => {
            contentControl.cannotDelete = false;
            contentControl.cannotEdit = false;
            contentControl.delete(false);
        });

        await context.sync();
    });
}
```

When `.delete` is called against the inner content control i get a `GeneralException`, but for the outer content control, it works. Do I need to do something differently to allow the deletion? I've allowed the outer one to be deleted, but that doesn't change anything.

*Edit:* After attempting Rick's suggestions to go through the "outer" content control's `contentControls` property, I'm able to delete some. The ones that can and cannot be deleted are generated the same way. I still get the unhelpful `GeneralException` on the `ContentControl.delete` call. I've also tried calling `.getRange(Word.RangeLocation.whole).delete()` and get the same `GeneralException`. It seems to be the last content control that is nested is the one that fails.

*Root cause* I lock my outer one from deletion. So if I unlock it from deletion, calling delete on the inner works but deletes the outer content control as well. Seems like a bug in Word. Are there workarounds?

Comment: I don't get an exception from your code, but I do find that contentControls.items.length is 0, so I think that your "Inner" tagged control is just not being seen. I think you have to first get a reference to the "Outer" content control and then call myOuterContentContol.contentControls.getByTag('Inner') to get the inner one. Please try that and if it works I'll make it the answer.

Comment: @RickKirkham what build are you on? Perhaps that’s changed...

Comment: I'm on Click-to-Run 1806 10214.20000.

Comment: @RickKirkham I'm on 1708 and can't go higher ATM. can you verify with your contacts at Microsoft that i have to use the inner ranges or not? heres my scriptlab: https://gist.github.com/daniel-white/0bf1ecbbdc8331d5415ef9d57d32d119

Comment: @RickKirkham i reworked my sample and i had no problems doing the nested. strange how i do get back something in 1708, but i guess its "fixed" in newer builds.

Comment: @RickKirkham also how can i find out exactly what caused the GeneralException - is there logging i can turn on? deleting seems sporatic to me

Comment: @DanielA.White, I am confused did you fixed the issue in 1708? we cannot repro. if so how did you fix it? or what was the state of the document when the call failed. A solid repro step will be helpful. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This does not repro in the latest builds. You can update to 16.0.10211.20004  in your insiders fast.

Comment: I can’t control what version I have not my customers

Comment: Are you in the monthly release channel?

Comment: No. My IT department has me restricted

Comment: oh  I see... i am confused in your previews answer, did you fixed the issue in 1708?

Comment: I came up with a workaround that isn’t ideal. The basic issue is that a parent content control is deleted by deleting its only child. That doesn’t make sense